# A design related issue, not being able to figure out what to change

Tags: html, css

here i am giving a live web site address http://www.bba-reman.com just select country UK or USA. a page will come. if u see the page in chrome & FireFox then it looks fine but if u see the page in IE then overlapping problem you noticed.

here i am giving the image of the problem area. please see this area in other browser then you can understand this is css issue. so please inspect that area with firebug and guide me what to change in css as a result UI should look same in all browser. looking for guidance. thanks

[image]

### EDIT

this way solved after getting guidance from @Piyush.

```
.arrange_collection_today
                    {
                        width: 216px;
                        color: #fff;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        display: block;
                        text-align: left;
                        height: 73px;
                        line-height: 23px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        padding: 6px;
                        float: right;
                        background-color: #3ab54b;
                        margin-right: 181px;
                        border-radius: 1px;
                        margin-top: 60px;

                        _margin-top:-60px; /* Only works in IE6 */
                        *margin-top:-60px; /* IE6, IE7 */
                        +margin-top:-60px;/* Only works in IE7*/
                        *+margin-top:-60px; /* Only works in IE7 */
                        margin-top:-60px\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
                        margin-top:-60px\0; /* IE8, IE9 */
                        margin-top:-60px\9\0;/*Only works in IE9*/                        
                    }
```

Comment: Please post code here, don't refer us to live sites. Eventually you'll fix the live site and this question will be useless. Create questions which remain useful and stand the test of time; Stackoverflow is not primarily your quick-fix personal help service.

Comment: Also tell us whether you have validated the CSS using http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and what version of IE is giving trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in IE is this specific line  with class `arrange_collection_today`

```
margin-top:60px;
```

You can try, to force IE only

```
margin-top:-60px
```

So change your css in a way that IE use `**margin-top:-60px**` and other browser use **`margin-top:60px;`**

Comment: how to write css in such way as a result if people open site in IE then this line work margin-top:-60px for other browser margin-top:60px; work. please guide. thanks

Comment: You can use the CSS hacks for browser so that different css class attributes work for different browsers. try this link to check how to use css hecks http://codemug.com/html/css-hacks-for-ie6ie7ie8ie9-and-ie10/

Comment: one more link is http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Comment: this link http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/ is not working

Comment: you saved my life bcoz i was not css guy but your link helped me to solve it. thanks

Comment: Your Welcome @Thomas. We are here to solve the problems.

Comment: can u tell me IE hack for IE 10 & 11. thanks

Comment: You can try for IE10 and IE11
==================
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
 .selector { property:value; }
}    refer link here https://gist.github.com/ricardozea/5549389  and https://philipnewcomer.net/2014/04/target-internet-explorer-10-11-css/